# Exporting the Safari (OSX) window to a remote Linux box

Tags: osx, remote

I have network access to a headless Mac mini running "OS X Server" (10.6.8 Snow Leopard). Sitting on my Linux desktop (Fedora) I can execute something like:

```
ssh myuser@imachost xeyes
```

and get the xeyes window popping up in my desktop. Typical X behavior.

Now I want to bring a Safari window, but that fails. The most I can get is Safari getting launched locally on the OS X machine, but the window is not exported to my Linux. 
If a put a monitor to the Mac mini I see Safari window open there.

How can I accomplish this ? (I don't want to deal with VNC... don't want the full desktop - I just want it to behave like xeyes)...

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  Safari windows are not drawn under the X server, so you can't tunnel those windows using X forwarding over SSH.